# Could not connect: Access denied for user php

Tags: php

I have an application written in C# and it does connect with the database.

Here's the error I'm getting:

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in (php file) on line 15
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Here is my code:

```
$mysql = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
if (!$mysql) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
```

I got this example from:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're just starting, I recommend you learn `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead. `MySQL` is deprecated and is soon to be removed.

Comment: are you sure that your username=username and password=password in mysql?

Comment: How about giving us the error mysql_error is printing?

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán I editted it.

Comment: check the username and password is correct

Comment: @Sundar It is... I am using this in c# and it works.

Comment: Add your complete error message which may be helpful to understand .. The error is returned by mysql_error() function

Comment: This issue happens only for password is wrong check it clearly.. Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @Sundar nvm I will be using Mysqli. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your username in mysql in probably not "username", as your password is not "password". Please change it to something like

```
 $mysql = mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);
```

where `$username` is variable with your db username and `$password` is variable with your db password.

Also it would be good thing to use `MySQLi` instead of `mysql_` functions.